# Getting an issue reading a txt file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a .txt file like this:

> 1. 20590772-6
> 2. Raul
> 3. ceo
> 4. 300001
> 5. 20535787-4
> 6. Valentin
> 7. ceo
> 8. 300002
> 9. 12345678-9
> 10. empleado1
> 11. empleado
> 12. 400000
> 13. 23456789-0
> 14. empleado2
> 15. empleado
> 16. 490900
> 17. 34567890-8
> 18. empleado3
> 19. empleado
> 20. 999999

Every 4 lines are part of a structure and for a reason when I'm printing it the first and second line combines showing for example "12345567-8Name" and not "12345567-8"

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct empleado{
  char rut_emp[10];
  char nombre_emp[20];
  char cargo_emp[20];
  int sbase;

  struct empleado *siguiente;
}empleado;

struct empleado *primero, *ultimo;


void leerArchivo(empleado lista[]){
  FILE *fp; 
  fp = fopen("empleados.txt", "r");
  int cont=0;
  int cont_emp=0;

  static char linea[5000];

  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

    if(fgets(linea, 5000, fp) != NULL) {
      linea[strcspn(linea, "\r\n")] = 0;
      char delim[] = " ";
      char *palabra_num = strtok(linea, delim);

      if(cont>=0 && cont<4){
        if(cont==3){
          lista[cont_emp].sbase=atoi(linea);
          cont_emp++;
          cont=0;
        }else if(cont==2){
          strcpy(lista[cont_emp].cargo_emp,linea);
          cont++;
        }else if(cont==1){
          strcpy(lista[cont_emp].nombre_emp,linea);
          cont++;
        }else if(cont==0){
          strcpy(lista[cont_emp].rut_emp,linea);
          cont++;
        } 
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
}

int main(void) {
  empleado lista_emp[5];

  leerArchivo(lista_emp);
  printf("Empleados: \n");
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("Rut: %s\n",lista_emp[i].rut_emp);
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",lista_emp[i].nombre_emp);
    printf("Cargo: %s\n",lista_emp[i].cargo_emp);
    printf("Numero: %i\n",lista_emp[i].sbase);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're copying 10 characters (e.g. `12345567-8`) plus a null byte into 10 bytes of storage for `rut_emp` — you didn't allow enough space for the terminating null byte.

Comment: Didn't know that, how can I fix it?

Comment: The simplest is to change the definition to `char rut_emp[11];`, but you should also be verifying that the string you try to copy into the structure fits.  So, since you need a string and the string must have 10 characters plus null, you must increase the size.  But you also need to validate that the input is OK, rejecting it if it is too long (or truncating it, or …).  Forgetting to account for the null byte at the end of a string is a very common problem in C programs.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: You want to follow @JonathanLeffler's instruction and also initialize lista_emp[5] to zero with `empleado lista_emp[5] = {0}` to set all memory cells as zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- And back in the old PC-DOS days (i.e. no mem protection), making the mistake of using strcpy, memcpy, or memset into a NULL pointer was sure to get your attention, especially if that variable was 0.  You would overwrite the system's interrupt vectors, which usually consisted of a random assortment of extended ASCII characters going across your screen, a few tab characters causing beeps, and then a crashed system that you had to power cycle since the <CTRL><ALT><DEL> was no longer recognized. BTDT. Program development on a non-memory-protected architecture is so FUN...

Comment: Live by the rule *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!*.  If you estimate your max input is 10-chars - double that, or use the next power of two after it, e.g. `char rut_emp[20];` or `char rut_emp[32];`. Better to be 500 characters too-long than one too-short...

Comment: Tried it but it seems to keep printing two lines e.g "12345678-9Name" instead of just "12345678-9"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minor variant of your code, with the size of `rut_emp` increased from 10 to 11, and with some error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct empleado
{
    char rut_emp[11];
    char nombre_emp[20];
    char cargo_emp[20];
    int  sbase;
    struct empleado *siguiente;
} empleado;

struct empleado *primero, *ultimo;

static void leerArchivo(empleado lista[])
{
    const char filename[] = "empleados.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int cont = 0;
    int cont_emp = 0;

    static char linea[5000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(linea, 5000, fp) != NULL)
        {
            linea[strcspn(linea, "\r\n")] = 0;

            if (cont >= 0 && cont < 4)
            {
                if (cont == 3)
                {
                    lista[cont_emp].sbase = atoi(linea);
                    cont_emp++;
                    cont = 0;
                }
                else if (cont == 2)
                {
                    if (strlen(linea) >= sizeof(lista[cont_emp].cargo_emp))
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Cargo Emp '%s' is too long\n", linea);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    strcpy(lista[cont_emp].cargo_emp, linea);
                    cont++;
                }
                else if (cont == 1)
                {
                    if (strlen(linea) >= sizeof(lista[cont_emp].nombre_emp))
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Nombre Emp '%s' is too long\n", linea);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    strcpy(lista[cont_emp].nombre_emp, linea);
                    cont++;
                }
                else if (cont == 0)
                {
                    if (strlen(linea) >= sizeof(lista[cont_emp].rut_emp))
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "RUT Emp '%s' is too long\n", linea);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    strcpy(lista[cont_emp].rut_emp, linea);
                    cont++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    empleado lista_emp[5];

    leerArchivo(lista_emp);
    printf("Empleados:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Rut %d:  %s\n", i, lista_emp[i].rut_emp);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", lista_emp[i].nombre_emp);
        printf("Cargo:  %s\n", lista_emp[i].cargo_emp);
        printf("Numero: %i\n", lista_emp[i].sbase);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With your data file, this produces the output:

```
Empleados:
Rut 0:  20590772-6
Nombre: Raul
Cargo:  ceo
Numero: 300001
Rut 1:  20535787-4
Nombre: Valentin
Cargo:  ceo
Numero: 300002
Rut 2:  12345678-9
Nombre: empleado1
Cargo:  empleado
Numero: 400000
Rut 3:  23456789-0
Nombre: empleado2
Cargo:  empleado
Numero: 490900
Rut 4:  34567890-8
Nombre: empleado3
Cargo:  empleado
Numero: 999999
```

If you were still running into problems, I have to deduce that you didn't make the change correctly, or you didn't recompile.